# Drop table in Oracle 10g, but use where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I drop a table in oracle, but I want to use a where condition in the query; for example:

```
drop table employees where employee_id='100';
```

Is this possible or not?

Comment: If you just want to delete some rows, use `DELETE` as per Ben's answer. If you want to drop the whole partition that contains that employee, then you can use `DROP PARTITION` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin002.htm#i1007479

Answer (score 11):

You're not looking to [`DROP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9003.htm#SQLRF01806) the table; dropping the table removes the entire table and all data therein.

It appears as though you want to remove some rows from the table. If this is the case you should use the [`DELETE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8005.htm#SQLRF01505) statement:

```
delete from employees where employee_id = 100;
```

It might be worth investigating some [basic functionality](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/) or taking a course before continuing.

Incidentally, 100 is a number. Using `'` implies that it's a string. If the datatype of the column EMPLOYEE_ID is a number you don't need to quote it.

Comment: 1+ For your explanation ,rare people do that these days

Comment: I always do @Moudiz :-).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to drop a table there is no need of checking some conditions.

If you need to specify where clause you are probably looking for deleting some rows. Better use delete.

Using condition to check for dropping a table is a new thing and i am gonna try it now.